# Cognos Content Store Query Paths

Tags: cognos

For daily operative issues, I need to recover the path of a report by entering the subject
of the email he receives.

*For example:* A customer receives a mail with the subject 'Sells report' and the report it's in 'Reports/Sells/Customer1_Report'

I think I must be able to do this by querying the [content store](http://it.toolbox.com/wiki/index.php/Cognos_Content_Store), but I don't know how to do this.

Have you done it? If you don't, do you know any tool for retreive this kind of info of the content store?

Thanks in advance, and sorry if this is too specific...

Comment: To be clear, you want to identify the searchpath of a report based on the subject of an email that delivered that report? That's a pretty odd request.

Comment: Yes, maybe I didn't explained it very well. I just want to find an easy way to find my reports (I have hundreds of folders and thousands of reports, agents, jobs..). And my users just say to me 'Hey, this report is not correct, and they show me the email) and with that info it's pretty hard to find where they are.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the Set Properties icon for any report object in Cognos Connection. It's the first icon under "Actions" and looks like a finger pointing at a box with red writing on it.

In the upper-right hand area of the default General tab you should see a link for "View the search path, ID and URL". Click that link to display the Search path, Unique ID (CAM) and Default action URL for the object.

Your users can easily cut-and-paste the Search Path entry into an email to give you a nice path like /content/folder[@name='Folder Name']/report[@name='Report Name'] in their error reports.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but they don't have access to Cognos connection. They just receive the report in an atachment. So the only information they have is:
- email subject
- email body
- atachments

Comment: You can insert a Layout Calculation into any report and use the ReportPath() function (under Report Functions folder in the Functions tab of the Report Expression editor) to have it display the path to the report in Cognos Connection. This may only be useful if you already have a universal header or footer that you can add it to, otherwise you will have to add the Layout Calculation object to every single report in your inventory. (Another reason to use Layout Component References to build re-usable templates!)

Comment: Thank you, this is a very good idea. But I don't have a common footer :( I would like to query the content store for retreive the path of the report querying by email subject.